# Resize Images on the Fly with AWS Lambda and Amazon API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I followed the tutorial on this page [HERE](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/)
but when I try to get a resized picture I get an "Access Denied"

Good: https://xxxx.amazonaws.com/mybucket/test.jpg
Error: https://xxxx.amazonaws.com/mybucket/300x300/test.jpg (access denied)

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
</Error>
```

Below my settings:

Bucket policy editor

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I created the trigger, I selected Security: OPEN. I'm just confused about the **YOUR_API_HOSTNAME_HERE**. In the example, the api hostname is h3ll0w0rld?

Answer (score 3):

GetObject action is not enough. You should give lambda permission to list the content as well . Also notice `Resources` section that I put.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Principal": { "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com" },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abdennour. I added your code and I get a error: Required filed Principal is missing. So I added "Principal": "*". Now I have a new error:    `<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Key>300x300/test.jpg</Key>
/KjC8yZnqmI1uLZq523OkiNrIn+p08qz+SzDU=</HostId>
</Error>`  I will investigate why I get this error.

Comment: @TylerDurden this error means the object is not in the bucket.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI you should mention that `s3:List*` should **not** be given to anonymous users, since this allows anyone anywhere to list all the objects in your bucket, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

@AbdennourTOUMI you're right. The "bucket policy" must be:
`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketNAME/*"
        }
    ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your bucket contains 300x300 folder containing the file. because, as @Michael-sqlbot said, it can indicate that the file does not exist.
Yes, In the example, the api hostname is h3ll0w0rld.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com. 
To get the resized picture, you need use your static website hosting endpoint - http://bucket_name.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/300x300/test.jpg 
then in your bucket  will be created a folder 300x300, which will contain 'test.jpg'